# Sometimes application windows are not clickable (after minimize / restore, they work again)

Tags: gnome, multiple-monitors, window

I have this weird problem, on my **Ubuntu 20.04** sometimes application windows (any window) are frozen. Which means they do not display correct (actual) data, also could not be **minimized/maximized/closed** with appropriate **window buttons**.

Example: Imagine you see a message notification for slack, but you have slack opened on another monitor without any new message. You minimize the window by clicking slack icon in favorites menu, then click it again to restore the window and voila, you see it refreshed and with the new message.

What could be possible cause to this problem? any ideas? does anyone else experienced this? How can i at least begin to investigate this issue?

Any advice whould be helpful, thanks!

PS: I have a notebook with external monitor in extended layout, both scaled

EDIT:
Some graphic card infos

```
$ lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 630 (Mobile)

$ sudo lshw -c video
*-display UNCLAIMED       
       description: 3D controller
       product: GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Ti Mobile]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:ec000000-ecffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d1ffffff ioport:3000(size=128) memory:ed000000-ed07ffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: UHD Graphics 630 (Mobile)
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:148 memory:eb000000-ebffffff memory:80000000-8fffffff ioport:4000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

Monitor is 25" Dell (IDK model number) connected with USB-c

Comment: Include information about your hardware, in particular graphics card, and details about your external monitor and how it is connected.

Comment: i have edited the question, what other info should i add? i'm using nouveau driver

Comment: *i'm using nouveau driver* No, you aren't, you're using none (that's what unclaimed means). Do the smart thing: Disable Secure Boot in UEFI and install the recommended Nvidia drivers version.

Comment: doesn't it mean i'm using nouveau + UHD Graphics 630? I'm rather new to linux, so please do correct me if i'm wrong. Btw I rather go with oss than propietary if there is a choice.